# kerasR giving error

Tags: r, deep-learning, keras

I am trying to use kerasR for deep learning in R. I am trying to reproduce the examples in the package. Trying the following code produces error:

```
library(kerasR)
mod <- Sequential()
```

The error is:

```
Error in Sequential() : attempt to apply non-function
```

Comment: The [onLoad](https://github.com/statsmaths/kerasR/blob/master/R/onLoad.R) function for that package tries to load the modules from python. It's really just an R wrapper for the python package. Do you have python installed and do you have both the "keras" and "numpy" python modules installed?

Comment: I have Anaconda python installed with numpy, theano and keras.

Comment: Does `reticulate::py_module_available("keras") ` return TRUE?

Comment: It returns FALSE, which probably means it cannot detect the keras in anaconda.

Comment: Do you have a virtual environment set up for your python or something? Maybe checkout the documentation for the `reticulate` package to see where it looks for python and installed packages.

Comment: I do not have a virtual environment. Does it have an issue with Python3? I will search the reticulate package documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to look at this issue in KerasR Github repo:
https://github.com/statsmaths/kerasR/issues/1

Basically you should check where is located your version of python and then use reticulate::use_python("PATH_TO_PYTHON") to tell the system where to find Python.

**Watch Out!**
You can load just one Python interpreter per session and the use_python() function doesn't warn you if there already is a loaded interpreter.
Moreover if you run py_config() it automatically loads the first interpreter that he finds (which, in your case, seems to be the wrong one!), thus you'd better call reticulate::use_python("PATH_TO_PYTHON") before anything else.