# Importing python module in R

Tags: python, r, reticulate

I am trying to import a python module in R using the `reticulate` package. The module can be found [here](https://github.com/nchavoshi/debot_api). I cloned the repository and ran `python setup.py install` which ran successfully. If I open a python shell, I'm able to import `debot`. However, when I try to import it in RStudio, I get the following error:

```
dbot=import("debot")
Error in py_module_import(module, convert = convert) : 
  ImportError: No module named debot
```

I am on macOS Sierra version 10.12.6 and installed python 3.6 through Anaconda. I have also tried giving the path to python as:

```
path_to_python <- "/anaconda/bin/python3.6"
use_python(path_to_python)
```

When I run python from a terminal, I get:

```
Python 3.6.1 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (x86_64)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:04:09) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Not sure if the path to python is correct.

Ok, did some more digging around and discovered that `reticulate` still refers to my older python path for python 2.7 which came as default with my Macbook. When I run `py_config()`, this is what I get:

```
python:         /usr/bin/python
libpython:      /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.dylib
pythonhome:     /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7:/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7
version:        2.7.10 (default, Feb  7 2017, 00:08:15)  [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.34)]
```

No matter what I try but I can't get `reticulate` to look at the correct path where the module has been installed using the `use_python()` function. I do believe this is an issue with `reticulate`. Any ideas what my next steps should be?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this package but I assume you did `library(reticulate)` and have read the relevant doc at `?import` ?  Also, are you able to import other python modules, including non-pip ones?  Is it just this module that is the problem?

Comment: Yes I did. In fact I faced no problems while running my script on Windows. I think its a Mac issue, or the python installation which ships with it as default.

Comment: OK, looks like a good question, sorry I got nothin...

Comment: If it helps, `which python` reveals `/anaconda/bin/python` and hence changed `path_to_python <- "/anaconda/bin/python"` but the result is the same.

Comment: Also when I run `python setup.py install`, it shows me `Installed /anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/debot-0.1-py3.6.egg`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43279062/kerasr-giving-error/43411909) I finally figured out. I think before calling any other function from the `reticulate` package, it is imperative to specify the path to python to use. Hence the order I am following now is:

```
library(reticulate)
path_to_python <- "/anaconda/bin/python"
use_python(path_to_python)
```

Comment: Dhiraj I  am also having same issue. But even with use_python command it is still picking up the default system python. Any comments?

Comment: I too am having the same problem and use_python is not working.

Comment: similar for me, then I realised my problem was that I ran py_config() first to check which one is loaded, but this command actually loads the default interpreter. so do not run this. the first thing has to be reticulate::use_python(path). hope that helped

Comment: I had the same problem. I restarted my R session and then it worked. Go figure?