# python in r: pandas not found

Tags: r, python-2.7, rstudio, reticulate

I am trying to improve my research by the combining of R and Python advantages. Reticulate package is a promising tool for this purpose. But something comes wrong...

```
devtools::install_github("rstudio/reticulate")
library(reticulate)

py_available()
```

[1] FALSE

```
py_config()
```

python:         /usr/bin/python

libpython:    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.dylib

pythonhome:  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7:/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7
version:        2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21)  [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)]

numpy:          /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy
numpy_version:  1.8.1

python versions found:

/usr/bin/python

/usr/local/bin/python

/usr/local/bin/python3

/Users/User/anaconda/bin/python

```
use_python(" /Users/User/anaconda/bin/python")
```

> I am using all "data science pack" under Anaconda. Thet is why the corresponded python version was chosen. All required packages are installed and they often in use via Jupiter notebook

```
py_available()
```

[1] TRUE

> Yes, as expected!

```
py_module_available("pandas")
```

[1] FALSE

> Not available for some reason(((

**Thank you in advance for the ideas))**

SessionInfo for a case:

R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X El Capitan 10.11.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] ru_RU.UTF-8/ru_RU.UTF-8/ru_RU.UTF-8/C/ru_RU.UTF-8/ru_RU.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] reticulate_1.1.0.9004

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] httr_1.3.1      compiler_3.4.1  R6_2.2.2        tools_3.4.1     withr_2.0.0     curl_2.8.1      memoise_1.1.0
 [8] Rcpp_0.12.12    git2r_0.19.0    digest_0.6.12   jsonlite_1.5    devtools_1.13.3

> 

Comment: are you able to use pandas inside a python script? Try reinstall pandas `sudo pip install pandas`

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to call `use_python` **immediately** after calling `library(reticulate)`, before `py_config` or anything else.

That worked for me. More details in this question: [Importing python module in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45861045/importing-python-module-in-r?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the second argument of the function, so it should be:

```
For expample use_python("/users/my_user/Anaconda3/python.exe",required = TRUE)
```

DONT forget the **required = TRUE**