# How to activate anaconda environment within R

Tags: python, r, anaconda

I have qiime2 program [https://qiime2.org](https://qiime2.org/) in my directory  `/home/owner/anaconda3/envs/qiime2-2019.1`. In Linux terminal, I run `source activate /home/owner/anaconda3/envs/qiime2-2019.1` to start this program.

I tried doing this within R studio as `system('source activate /home/owner/anaconda3/envs/qiime2-2019.1')`, but it it gives me this error: `sh: 1: activate: not found
Warning message:
In system('activate /home/owner/anaconda3/envs/qiime2-2019.1') :
  error in running command`

Is there a way to activate anaconda env within R or Rstudio?

Comment: Does quime comes with R installed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set up conda-installed R for use with RStudio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38534383/how-to-set-up-conda-installed-r-for-use-with-rstudio)

Answer (score 10):

Yes there are multiple ways I recommend looking into the reticulate package but basically, R Studio preview 1.2 is capable of "finding" your conda environments.

My prefered way is:

```
library(reticulate)
library(tidyverse)

# Seeing your enviroments
conda_list()

#Using it
conda_list()[[1]][1] %>% 
  use_condaenv(required = TRUE)

#Checking python

import platform
print(platform.python_version())
```

**Links**

Reticulate: https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/

My blog: https://twosidesdata.netlify.com/2019/03/23/exploratory-data-analysis-basic-pandas-and-dplyr/#how-to-set-up-reticulate

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting this error now : `> conda_list()[[1]][3] %>%
+   use_condaenv(required = TRUE)
Error in use_python(conda_env_python, required = required) : 
  Required version of Python '/home/owner/anaconda3/envs/qiime2-2019.1/bin/python' cannot be used because another version of Python ('/usr/bin/python') is already initialized for this process.`

Comment: I never had this problem my suggestion would be to either try what Shivan is saying or restarting your R session, I would mention that I usually use python inside an Rmarkdown document so maybe it doesn't work as well on an R script

Comment: a minor modification that: #Checking python
`platform <- import("platform")` & `print(platform$python_version())`

Comment: `Error in use_python(python, required = required) : 
  Specified version of python '~/miniconda3/envs/salmon/bin/python' does not exist.`

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, but found some ways one can activate. One is using the library reticulate mentioned above, but I use it this way:

```
library(reticulate)
use_condaenv("py2_env")    #activate an environment e.g py2_env
base::system(paste0("sh py2_env_program_to_run.sh"))   #run a program that requires that environment
```

With reticulate im not sure though how you would deactivate the environment.

The second way, I wrote a little bash script called 'env_eval.sh'

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH=/opt/conda/bin:$PATH
export PATH

eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)"
```

Then I reference it in my R script everytime i want to use conda e.g:

```
base::system2(paste0("sh ",run_folder,"/code/bash/env_eval.sh conda activate py2_env && run_py2_env_program.sh"))
```

I can even deactivate a conda environment with this method:

```
base::system(paste0("sh ",run_folder,"/code/bash/env_eval.sh conda deactivate && run_program_that_should_not_be_in_any_conda_env.sh"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, I do not use Rstudio but from some searches, I can suggest you try by setting python path instead of activating environment by Conda activate.

You can select which python interpreter you are going to use and here it.

```
    library(reticulate)
```

```
    path_to_python <- "/anaconda3/envs/qiime2-2019.1/python"
```

```
    use_python(path_to_python, required = TRUE)
```

here are some answers for the same type of question:

1> https://stackoverflow.com/a/54813273/9071644

2> https://stackoverflow.com/a/45891929/9071644

3> https://stackoverflow.com/a/43411909/9071644

Answer (score 1):

I think it could not be successful to enter the conda environment in R console, but you still can use the environment command by indicating the path.

For instance, my path of qiime is `/home/username/miniconda3/envs/qiime2-2019.7/bin/qiime`.
If you want to run the code like `qiime info`, you can use the command:

```
system("/home/username/miniconda3/envs/qiime2-2019.7/bin/qiime info")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Python in RStudio, the best way to get it going is to create a separate 'reticulate' environment using Anaconda.

Part of the reason is that so you can use RMarkdown for your output requires PyQt5 which will break your Jupyter/Spyder environments if you overwrite PyQt.

Then you have to make an .Renviron file like [this setup.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50145643/unable-to-change-python-path-in-reticulate-r/60048094#60048094) which points R to the proper Python env.  Otherwise, the default for RStudio seems to be a miniconda environment.

Once your separate reticulate environment is set and you have .Renviron pointing to it, all of your Python package installs should go into that environment.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when trying to run gdal commands through an R system call. I found that I needed to use the shell() function rather than system() to call my command. Once conda is initialized in a cmd.exe (by running `conda init`), the shell(cmd) call worked successfully through R.

```
shell('conda activate gdal-env && gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:6339 -t_srs EPSG:6414 in.tif out.tif')
```